# Minimum Spanning tree from array list

Tags: java, arraylist, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm wondering if it's possible to find the minimum spanning tree from an ArrayList.

This is what I currently have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GraphReading 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    File f= new File("Bridges.txt");
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(f);

    ArrayList < ArrayList<Integer>  >   Vertices = new ArrayList<>();

    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
        String Line =     sc.nextLine();
        String numbers[] = Line.split(" ");

        ArrayList<Integer>  List = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i <  numbers.length ;i++)
        {
                if(numbers[i].equals("")==false)
                    List.add(  Integer.parseInt( numbers [i]));
        }
        Vertices.add(List);
    }
    printAllvertices(Vertices);
}
public static  void printAllvertices(  ArrayList < ArrayList<Integer>  >   Vertices  )
{
    for(int i=0;i<  Vertices .size();i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Vertice "+i+ " has ");
             ArrayList<Integer>  List =  Vertices.get(i);
             for(int j=0;j<List.size();j++)
             {
                 System.out.print(List.get(j)+" ");
             }
             System.out.println();




    }

}

}
```

I was thinking about just finding the minimum number from each of the vertices but I wasn't too sure that would necessarily work the way I wanted it too.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can! I found this site that has some nice documentation on how to do it using PRIM's algorithm.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-5-prims-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-2/

You might need to convert a bit of code around, but that should be trivial. Looking for just the cheapest edges is a solution, but may not always result in the minimum spanning tree. This way you might accidentally make "detours" in your graph, making your tree larger than intended.

Comment: Could you mark the answer as "answered" by pressing the green check if it really helped? It would help other users who have the same question, as you. :-)